# DOM methods not working in Chrome, safari, mozilla, working fine in IE*

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

here my code scenario is , when user click on add so dynamically one row got added in table for that i am using javascript function..
html code is like below::

```
<td class="addtxt" onClick="addParameterValue('parameterFields','fieldvalue','actualdt','name','shortname','defaultvalue','secured','syncid')">Add</td>
```

the function which i m calling is like below::

```
function addParameterValue(tableid,fieldvalue,actualdt,name,shortname,defaultvalue,secured,syncid)
{

 var fieldname1=document.getElementById(fieldvalue).value;  
    var fieldValueLength =  document.getElementById(fieldvalue).maxLength;

        var tableRowsLength = document.getElementById(tableid).rows.length;
        var textBoxesLength = tableRowsLength - 6;
        var idValue = fieldvalue+1;
        benIncr=tableRowsLength;
        var flag = true;
        flag=fieldMandatory(fieldname1);
        if(flag)
        {
           var tbl = document.getElementById(tableid);
            lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
            iteration= lastRow;
            var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
            row.className='detailsPageValue';

             var absence0 = row.insertCell(0);
             addTextBox(fieldvalue);
             textBoxRow.id=fieldvalue+benIncr;
             textBoxRow.maxLength="6"
             textBoxRow.onkeyup=function(){convertLowerCaseToUpperCase(this.id)}
             absence0.appendChild(textBoxRow);
             var node1= document.createTextNode(' ');
             absence0.appendChild(node1);

             var absence1 = row.insertCell(1);
             addTextBox(actualdt);
             textBoxRow.id=actualdt+benIncr;
             textBoxRow.readOnly=true;
             absence1.appendChild(textBoxRow);
             textBoxRow.className='textStyle_80';
             var node2= document.createTextNode(' ');
             absence1.appendChild(node1);
             jqueryCalender(actualdt+benIncr);

             var absence2 = row.insertCell(2);
             addTextBox(name);
             textBoxRow.id=name+benIncr;
             absence2.appendChild(textBoxRow);

             var absence3 = row.insertCell(3);
             addTextBox(shortname);
             textBoxRow.id=shortname+benIncr;
             absence3.appendChild(textBoxRow);

             var absence4 = row.insertCell(4);
             addCheckBox(defaultvalue)
             absence4.appendChild(checkBoxRow);

             var absence5 = row.insertCell(5);
              addCheckBox(secured)
             absence5.appendChild(checkBoxRow);

             var absence6 = row.insertCell(6);
             addTextBox(syncid);
             textBoxRow.id=syncid+benIncr;
             textBoxRow.onblur = function(){checkNumeric(syncid+benIncr)} 
             absence6.appendChild(textBoxRow);

             var absence7 = row.insertCell(7);
             addDeleteImage();
             absence7.appendChild(deleteImage); 


        }
        else
         {
            alert("First Row should be added");
            return false;
         }
}
```

under that you can fine i am calling one function which is "addText" which is like below::

```
function addTextBox(textboxid)
     {

        var txtBoxIncrement=0;
        var textLength=document.getElementById(textboxid).maxLength;
        var textSize=document.getElementById(textboxid).size;
        var textClass=document.getElementById(textboxid).className;
        textBoxRow=document.createElement('input');
        textBoxRow.type='text';
        textBoxRow.name=textboxid;
        //textBoxRow.maxLength=textLength;
        textBoxRow.size=textSize;
        textBoxRow.id=textboxid+txtBoxIncrement+'';
        txtBoxIncrement++;
        textBoxRow.className=textClass;
     }
```

now the main thing comes... here i am calling DOM methods which are .maxLength, .size and .className ... which are working fine in IE* but not working for chrome, safari, mozilla firefox..

guys plz help me out .. thanks in advance... :)

Comment: I checked in FF, Opera and can see that they are working.

Comment: and @Harry for chrome and safari is not working still!!!

Comment: nope for Chrome, Safari also I tested just now and it is working. Can you create a jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: @Harry actually now i come to know that its working, but in my code i am adding text field for date.. and its giving me error for that perticular field only....

Comment: As I mentioned earlier can you please create a jsFiddle for your code. It will be easier to find the problem. Interesting I find another issue in all browsers. Fetching the max length value is correct, but for some reason the value gets set as 6 for the new fields :( Does this happen for you too?

Answer (score 0):

Try using getAttribute

```
document.getElementById(textboxid).getAttribute("maxlength")
```

Comment: not working same error its throwing... actually right now i came to know that it is throwing error when its adding field for date... and for date its not getting the maxLength..